# Restricting Web Service Calls in Azure

Tags: asp.net, web-services, azure

I have a web site that makes calls to a web service.  The web service currently restricts calls to be made only from the web site using IP restriction.

Now I am trying to move both sites to Azure Websites but I can no longer depend on a static IP address for calls from the web site because Azure Websites do not support static IPs for out-bound calls.

Azure Websites also do not accept client certificates.

How to I restrict calls to my web service to only be from my web site?

Comment: Move to using an authorisation header that you pass from your website to the API service? Something along the lines of: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/18/A-WebAPI-Basic-Authentication-Authorization-Filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Azure Web Sites do not accept client certificates, I decided to take another approach.  This solution uses ASP.NET's Forms Authentication and authorize a system user between services.

For this to work, each server must enable Forms authentication and be assigned the **same** machine key. I found it only works with the compatibility mode set to `Framework45`.

```html
    
<system.web>
    <machineKey compatibilityMode="Framework45" 
                validation="SHA1" 
                validationKey="14E2DFC..." 
                decryption="AES" 
                decryptionKey="93923..."/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="/SecurityService.asmx?op=authenticate" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow users="System" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Then generate and add a Forms authentication cookie to your web service (or any other HTTP call). Note that the Forms cookie had to be converted to a `System.Net.Cookie`.

```
var websiteService = new WebsiteService.WebsiteService();
websiteService.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
var websiteServiceUrl = new Uri(websiteService.Url);
var authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie("System", 
                                                    false, 
                                                    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
var authenticationCookie = new System.Net.Cookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, 
                                                authCookie.Value, 
                                                FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath, 
                                                websiteServiceUrl.Host);
websiteService.CookieContainer.Add(authenticationCookie);
```

Now all your authorizations can be configured in the authorization element in your web.config file as shown above.